# writing data in access file

Tags: java, user-interface, ms-access, netbeans

i'm developing a system that will take the user input and safe it in access file as database for registration system

```
 DBClass DB = new DBClass();
    DB.WrieToDatabase(jTextFieldID.getText(), jTextFieldname.getText(), jTextFieldemail.getText(), jPasswordFieldpass.getText(), jComboBoxgendar.getSelectedItem() +"" );
```

but when i run the code it gives the following error message:

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:odbc:Driver=(Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)};DBQ=store.accdb;DriverID=22;READONLY=false}
Error: Record could not be inserted into the database

Answer (score 0):

From your Error above ,You are missing a Database driver.Based on the version of MS Access file you are using you have to download a database driver. [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) is a link for DB driver for MS Access 2010